# Qt5 on Buildroot : fonts not rendered

Tags: fonts, qt5, buildroot

I'm using Buildroot 2018.11 and Qt5, no OpenGL.

I can launch my application with the `-platform xcb` in Xorg or `-platform linuxfb:fb=/dev/fb0` in the console.

However, in both cases, the fonts are not rendered : absolutely no text is displayed (menu bar, labels, etc.).

I enabled Qt5 fontconfig support. I have some fonts under `/usr/share/fonts` (`X11/` and `liberation/`). I made a symlink (`ln -s /usr/share/fonts /usr/lib/fonts`) so that Qt does not complain.

I'm really stuck here. Any idea ?

Comment: Is your fontconfig database rebuilt? Does fc-list show the correct font list for your system?

Comment: Right. I enabled `fontconfig` support and rebuilt qt5base. Now I've got letters and numbers. However, I can't change the font with the `-fn` option. So, it's like 80% resolved.

Comment: I have no idea what the `-fn` option does, what kind of application are we talking about? (Widgets, QML?) Did you try setting a different default font via QGuiApplication::setFont?

Comment: Possibly, but it's just a detail in my case, so I won't investigate the font change any further.

Comment: @dplamp. Can you please explain how did you get x11 working on buildroot? I'm having trouble setting it up on raspberry pi4:(

Comment: @IMAN4K : On an older build with a RPi, I had this module configuration : https://pastebin.com/uMbcH2Hv Then ask on the Buildroot mailing list. I use FluxBox, it's very light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by enabling `fontconfig` and rebuilding qt5base.